# Container doesn't allow type children typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

Container is component extended from `@material-ui/core` and it doesn't accept children with type `React.ReactNode`.

**Layout.tsx:**

```
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";

type LayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>{children}</Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works when, Container is replaced with a div tag. So, the issue is with MaterialUI's `Container`.

The only fix I found was to edit the internal Container code and,

```
-    children: NonNullable<React.ReactNode>;
+    children?: React.ReactNode;
```

But changing internal Container code run into some issue later in future.

Is there any other way to fix this ?

The type error I get now is,

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children: boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined; fixed?: boolean | undefined; maxWidth?: false | ... 5 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ContainerTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.ts(2769)
Container.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children: boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined; fixed?: boolean | undefined; maxWidth?: false | ... 5 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
Container.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined; fixed?: boolean | undefined; maxWidth?: false | ... 5 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does accept `React.ReactNode`, but the type also contains null and undefined. It is a union type of the following:

```
ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined
```

The `NonNullable<React.ReactNode>` simply ensures that null/undefined is not passed in, so it will have a type of:

```
ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean
```

You simply have to assert that `children` is not null/undefined, otherwise just pass in an empty string:

```
<Container>{children ?? ''}</Container>
```

Comment: Thanks! `<Container>{children!}</Container>` solved it :)

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas You need to know that your solution is an escape hatch, since it will not be able to guarantee that `children` is null/undefined. It only forces TypeScript to see it as such. Using the null coalescence operator is way safer.